# We randomly chose a number on the interval $[0,1]$. Find the probability that the first $10$ decimals of the chosen number are all equal to $1$

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-measure

This question was part of a test on an advanced probability class, centered around Lebesgue Measure.

> Let $\Omega=[0,1]$ be a Borel $\sigma-$Algebra and $P([a,b])=b-a$, $0\le a\le b\lt1$ the Lebesgue probability measure. We randomly chose a number on the interval $[0,1]$. Find the probability that the first $10$ decimals of the chosen number are all equal to $1$.

So, if I am not mistaken the Lebesgue measure of the desired probability is $\neq0$. So the probability itself must be $\neq0$. Although and for what it's worth, intuitively-to me that is-that does not seem to be the case. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Aren't the decimals (in the base-ten expansion) basically iid random variables uniformly distributed in $\{0,\dots,9\}$?

Comment: @ClementC. Honestly I do not know :-). Intuitively it would seem so. If so the probability is zero?

Comment: Rather something like $1/10^{10}$.

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you for the answer! Still, the numbers that satisfy the desired condition are infinite, right?

Comment: Yes -- you have infinitely many number (actually, even uncountably) satisfying the condition. And also uncountably many *not* satisfying the condition. Thinking in terms of intuition from the discrete/finite-space probability setting may not lead to the right idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two approaches:

- In the base-$d$ expansion, the decimals are i.i.d. random variables uniformly distributed in $\{0,\dots, d-1\}$ (this does require proving). From there, the probability is $\frac{1}{d^{10}}  = \frac{1}{10^{10}}$.
- This is computing the probability that the number falls in the interval $[a,b]$ with $a = 0.1111111111$ and $b=0.111111111199999\dots = 0.1111111112$. From there, $b-a = 0.0000000001 = 10^{-10}$, so the probability is $P([a,b]) = \frac{1}{10^{10}}$.